# Skip secondary page on RSS feeds

Tags: iphone, rss

I have an RSS feed for my iPhone app.  Right now, you see the list of RSS items on the page.  Then when you tap on the RSS item, it brings you to a secondary page that displays the RSS title, date, content, etc. and the title links out to the associated link.

Any way to skip this page and go right from the first RSS page, to the linked page?

Answer (score 0):

If you provide the code you might get more help...did you get this off the web that you can give a link to, or is it your own code?

Either way, it's most likely located in **didSelectRowAtIndexPath**, and there you would tell the RSS to grab the link and go there